# Intellij having trouble with code completion under Kotlin 1.2

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea, corda, intellij-plugin

I'm having trouble setting up the development environment for Corda. It seems IntelliJ's code completion feature is malfunctioning. I suspect that it's because incompatible kotlin language version (v1.2.71, used by Corda 4) with IntelliJ's kotlin-plugin version (v1.5).

[This is what I want IntelliJ to do when I'm typing the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EioC9.gif)

[This is what actually happened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vatB8.gif). As can be seen, no auto-completion or method suggestion showsed up.

The above two snippets are recorded in the same setting, but why is it working in the first case but failed in the second? How can I configure my environment so code completion can work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said, the problem is the not compatibility with the latest version of the Kotlin plugin. To develop smoothly with Corda 4.x it is better to use an older version of IntelliJ (2020). It is frustrating, I know. Corda 5 support for Kotlin will be, hopefully, better.